# Is there any math foundation for map/reduce?

Tags: computer-science

For a while I was thinking that you just need a map to a monoid, and then reduce would do reduction according to monoid's multiplication.

First, this is not exactly how monoids work, and second, this is not exactly how map/reduce works in practice.

Namely, take the ubiquitous "count" example. If there's nothing to count, any map/reduce engine will return an empty dataset, not a neutral element. Bummer.

Besides, in a monoid, an operation is defined for two elements. We can easily extend it to finite sequences, or, due to associativity, to finite ordered sets. But there's no way to extend it to arbitrary "collections" unless we actually have a sigma-algebra.

So, what's the theory? I tried to figure it out, but I could not; and I tried to go google it but found nothing.

Comment: What do you mean by map/reduce?

Comment: Asking on the stackexchange CS site will work much better than here, where you'll have to explain whatmap/reduce is :)

Comment: Even though I have heard of map/reduce several times and even seen some examples, I'd like to see the closest thing the OP knows to a definition of map/reduce. Certainly it won't be an exact definition, since this is what the OP is searching for, but at least it will probably be more formal and less handwaving than what I know about it.

Comment: Lookup monad instead of monoid.

Comment: (reduction need not be associative though...)

Comment: Not math and not research level. This question belongs to cs.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes.

Ok, while that was fun, let's give you a real answer.  As François mentionned, the key word is 'Monad'.  Basically/roughly your programming language forms a category, with types as the objects, and functions as the arrows.  Then 'map' is the action of a functor on arrows, and 'reduce' is an ordered fold, which is (again roughly) the 'bind' of a monad -- see [MapReduce as a Monad](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/MapReduce_as_a_monad) as a starting point.  For the semantics of 'fold', I rather like [this paper](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/richard.bird/online/BirdPaterson99Generalised.pdf) by Bird and Paterson on (generalized) folds.

Comment: Merci beaucoup Jacques!

Comment: Hmm. the discussion by the first link is about "generalized monad", Haskell style. While it is probably feasible to split the notion into two functors, declaring the second one a monad, I'd stay away from the arbitrariness of programming thinking and hold to a more mathematical interpretation.

As to the second paper, monads are not even mentioned there. Instead, as expected, it talks about monoids being used for reduction; and duly so. More, it defines the monoid on Map type that is being used in map/reduce, thus answering my question.


Answer (score 0):

You might also like this:

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.104.5859&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: The link goes to the paper "Google’s MapReduce Programming Model — Revisited" by Ralf Lämmel (Microsoft).  Here is an HTML abstract page for the linked paper: https://core.ac.uk/display/20722901